# query a list of project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying out the python SDK for gcp.  here is a simple script that works a project named "my-project-name".

what do I do if I want to get a list of every project in my organization?

many thanks

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

from pprint import pprint
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
project_id = 'my-project-name'
request = service.projects().get(projectId=project_id)
response = request.execute()
pprint(response)
```

Comment: I figured it out.  thank you

Comment: Maybe post your own answer so that others in the future will learn?   If you don't think the answer is of value, maybe delete the question? Thank you for posting that it is resolved.

Comment: I wrote an article that shows how to use both Python libraries to list projects. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-iam-listing-projects/

Comment: that is a very helpful article, thank you so much